# Photo merging iPhone app that won't reduce the picture resolution

Tags: photography, image-editor, iphone-app, merge

I have been looking for a very simple app that would merge two or more photos into one in my iPhone. I have tried `Photo Shake`, `Filterstorm`, `Cut Paste Photos - Chop your ...` and also its paid pro version, `Cut Paste Pro Full Edition - Make ...` and have not been happy with none of them at all. The reason is that iPhone 5 has a decent camera and it takes good, high-res pictures, and if I go to Photoshop and merge these photos there, they will never lose quality, because obviously, when there's a fixed-size screen in which there's one picture, if you want to display two pictures in the same screen area, your pictures will need to be zoomed out to fit in there, and this definitely does not have anything to do with quality loss and I cannot see why all these apps mess around with picture size when they do the merging which leads in unreadable text if you have any in your pictures.

So, does anyone know any app that would do the job better, or am I the only one suffering from this problem and people don't care about photo resolutions in mobile phones these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used [Pixlr Express](https://pixlr.com/mobile/) by Autodesk on my Android phone (it's [available on iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/app/pixlr-express-plus/id526783584?mt=8) too) and the results are great, the JPEG compression is lossy of course, but you're also able to save it on PNG format, without any quality loss. Note that you can only *merge* pictures, not *add* pictures together, like one below another and things like that. It also has lots of other features like filters, effects, borders, fonts, etc. All for free.

I use it mostly for taking pictures of the systems I repair and add an image label of my trademark. Something like this (a JPEG I composed a few weeks ago):

[image: QL IT]

[(link to full-size picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDtuk.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm just about to try and see how it works. (:

Comment: Ok... Looks like the quality is good, but now I have the problem that it automatically crops the images from two sides, i.e. I can't zoom out a rectangular image to have its width fit into the square... :-/

Comment: Question answered! I noticed I can play with the aspect ratio among the setting options. Thanks!